# How to add / change footer in wordpress as a plugin feature?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've created a custom widget area in the plugin I'm creating.

```
function arphabet_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'Home right sidebar',
    'id'            => 'home_right_1',
    'before_widget' => '<div>',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="rounded">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );

dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' );
```

And to enable showing the widgets stored in this widget I have inserted this code inside the footer.php of the theme I'm currently using for testing.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ) ) : ?>
                <div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget- 
 area" role="complementary">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home_right_1' ); ?>
                </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

It works, when I add widgets to my widget area, they are shown in footer of the website. But I want to make the plugin works without changing the footer.php manually. How can I check which theme is activated and then find that theme, the footer.php file and add that code exacltly where I want (to be shown below any other footer created with the theme when is installed. Also, I would like to remove the footer that was generated before.

Comment: Check this link for reference to 'wp_footer' action. This might be useful for you.
Regarding your requirement to remove the footer generated by active theme, I guess that will not be possible since the footer that is displayed is rendered by the code in footer.php of the active and I don't see any way for you to remove that code dynamically via your plugin without messing up the site.

Comment: Thanks for answering? Do you have any idea how can I implement this plugin feature? To add my custom html to the footer. I will read about wp_footer, thank you.

Comment: You can add your custom html below the footer generated by the active theme. But I don't think you can remove the footer html of the active theme via your plugin.

Comment: You mean with the wp_footer or? No problem, the footer generated with the active theme can stay, I will delete it manually.